# Limit Options Based On Previous Choices in a Bundled Item

Tags: grouped-products

### **Here’s a simple example of what I want to do with a bundled product.**

Say I’m building a computer and I have to pick my components from drop down menus.

I pick an AMD Motherboard, that means only AMD CPUs will work for that motherboard. So when I pick the AMD Motherboard I need the intel CPUs to disappear from the next drop down menu to prevent a customer from building an incompatible computer.

Is this something Magento can already do? If not is there a extension that can possibly do what i’m asking?

**Thanks for any replies!**

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done out of the box.
I found [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dependent-custom-options-bundle.html) that seams to let you build a restriction between bundle items and custom options.
I haven't tested it.

Also what you want ca be achieved through configurable products, but I doubt that this is the way to go for computer parts.